Custom Hibernate Annotation Not Triggering for Non-@Id Field in Spring Boot Application
What I want to achieve
I am trying to automatically generate a unique flightNumber for a field in a FlightInstance entity before it gets saved to the database. The flightNumber is not the primary key (@Id) and should be generated using a custom sequence logic with a prefix.
What I have done so far

Created a custom annotation to mark the flightNumber field:

@IdGeneratorType(value = FlightNumberSequenceGenerator.class)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD,FIELD})
public @interface FlightNumberSequence {

    String name();
    String prefix() default "FWF-";
    int startWith() default 1;
    int incrementBy() default 1;
}


Implemented a custom generator:

public class FlightNumberSequenceGenerator implements BeforeExecutionGenerator {

    private final String prefix;
    private final int incrementBy;

    public FlightNumberSequenceGenerator(FlightNumberSequence config) {
        System.out.println("Hello from FlightNumberSequenceGenerator");
        this.prefix = config.prefix();
        this.incrementBy = config.incrementBy();
    }

    @Override
    public Object generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object owner, Object currentValue, EventType eventType) {
        System.out.println("Hello from FlightNumberSequenceGenerator");
        return session.doReturningWork(connection -> {
            try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT next_val FROM flight_number_sequence FOR UPDATE");
                if (resultSet.next()) {
                    int nextVal = resultSet.getInt("next_val");
                    statement.executeUpdate("UPDATE flight_number_sequence SET next_val = " + (nextVal + incrementBy));
                    return prefix + nextVal;
                } else {
                    throw new IdentifierGenerationException("Unable to fetch the next sequence value.");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IdentifierGenerationException("Error generating flight number.", e);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public EnumSet<EventType> getEventTypes() {
        return EventTypeSets.INSERT_ONLY;
    }
}


Annotated the flightNumber field in my FlightInstance entity:

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class FlightInstance extends FlyWellModel {

    private boolean isFullyBooked;
    @Column(unique = true)
    @FlightNumberSequence(name = "flight_number_sequence", startWith = 1000, incrementBy = 3)
    private String flightNumber;
    private LocalDateTime departureTime;
    private LocalDateTime arrivalTime;
    private int baggageAllowance;
    @OneToOne
    private AirCraft airCraft;
    @OneToOne
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Flight flight;
    @Enumerated(STRING)
    private FlightStatus status;
    @OneToMany()
    @ToString.Exclude
    private List<FlightSeat> flightSeat;
}


My base model (FlyWellModel) includes the @Id field and other shared attributes:

@Getter
@Setter
@SuperBuilder
@EntityListeners(value = {AuditingEntityListener.class})
@MappedSuperclass
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FlyWellModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private String id;
    private String publicId;
    @CreatedDate
    LocalDateTime createdDate;
    @LastModifiedDate
    LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;
    @CreatedBy
    @Builder.Default
    String createdBy = "SYSTEM";

    String createdByRole;
    @LastModifiedBy
    String lastModifiedBy;

    @PrePersist
    private void generatePublicId(){
        publicId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
}

The challenge I am facing
The FlightNumberSequenceGenerator custom generator is not being triggered. I added print statements in the generate() method but confirmed that it is not getting called. The flightNumber field remains null after saving the entity to the database.
What I suspect
Since the flightNumber field is not the @Id field, Hibernate may not be handling the generator for it automatically.
My custom annotation might require additional configuration to hook into the entity lifecycle.
What I want to know
How can I properly configure my custom annotation to trigger the generator logic automatically before saving the entity?
Is there a restriction on using custom annotations or custom generators for fields that are not primary keys? What am I missing in the setup to make this work?

You probably need to use @ValueGenerationType instead of @IdGeneratorType in FlightNumberSequence
